# Биллинг, и тарификация учетных записей несколькими способами.

Tags: интерфейс, модульность, биллинг, тарификация

Привет всем!
Поскольку Я недавно решил завязать с велосипедостроением для проектов, нацеленных на продакшн, и принесение прибыли, понял, что некоторые подходы к организации приложений были не верны.

Сейчас у меня есть вопрос такого плана: Есть пользователи, они покупают у меня игровой хостинг. Хочу иметь такую систему, которая бы могла тарифицировать клиентов как по количеству слотов, так и по ресурсам, затраченным на игро-сервера этих пользователей. Собственно, как считать бабло - Я знаю, но не знаю, Как организовать... эмм.., как бы это назвать, модульность, что-ли, т.е., как биллингу сказать, что пользователя А нужно тарифицировать по количеству игровых слотов, а пользователя Б - по потребленным ресурсам.

Мониторинг для этой системы написать мне не составит труда.

Полагаю, нужно реализовать какой-то интерфейс? В общем, пока вопросов больше, чем ответов. Буду благодарен за советы, и идеи)

Comment: Тарифными планами. Если градаций не много, то можно не заморачиваться и засунуть методики расчетов жестко в код.

Comment: Агенты по категориям(у нас например по телефоний,по тв, по домофонам, и т.д) должны считать согласно тарифу, как сказал выше товарищ @SilverIce.